# Expected Value/Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

[The question is attached, I was solving problems on probability and came across this
PS: it's not a homework problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hbiT.jpg)

I was trying to first to generate a recursion as:

$$P(n)=P(n-1)/2 + P(n+1)/2,$$ where $P(n)$ is the probability to reach nth position.
Now, calculating $P(1)$ , was getting tough since it's involving a lot of case work like reaching 1st position after 1st pass,3rd pass.. and so on

Please help.

Comment: Since the tray passing is random, my guess would be that the candy averse person should sit as far away from you as possible.

Comment: What is the specific source of the problem (i.e. which problem in which book)?  Also, from the source, what previously solved problems, worked examples, or theorems do you think might be pertinent?  Please do not respond with a comment.  Instead, please respond by editing your posting to include this information.

Comment: @user2661923 this is a classic question with a slightly surprising answer.  Try it with you and three other people to see what happens in that small case.

Comment: @user2661923 The source is the university problem set,no such theorems were given there.

Comment: @Henry, If you could give a hint to proceed further,please.

Comment: Crusador:  As I suggested to @user2661923, try it with  you and three other people to see what happens in that small case.  Then see if the same result can be applied to more people.

Comment: @Henry I have tried,but not able to draw any conclusion that relates both of the problems.